# ROSSerializationException: field data exceeds specified width [int32]

Tags: python, ros-kinetic, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

The following error is appearing in my terminal:

```
[ERROR] [1601452123.044766]: bad callback: <bound method LECTURA_CLASS.callback of <__main__.LECTURA_CLASS instance at 0x7f55f2b772d8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/home/sara/catkin_ws/src/canusb/script/lectura.py", line 285, in callback
    self.enc_pub.publish(var_enc)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 886, in publish
    raise ROSSerializationException(str(e))
ROSSerializationException: field data exceeds specified width [int32]
```

I print the data value and it is 4294967234, but his type is int32 so the real meaning is -62.

var_enc is an structure like this:

```
int8 encID
int32 time
int32 data
```

So the data field is wanted to be int32, but I write it on this line:

```
var_enc.data = int(encB)
```

So, what type of cast must I do to avoid this error?

If you require another extra information please ask me.

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04, with ROS Kinetic, so the version of python is 2.7.

Best regards.
Alessandro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362569/rosserializationexception:-field-data-exceeds-specified-width-%5Bint32%5D/) by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2020-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved substracting 2^32 to the data, so is now an integer of 32 bits.

---

Originally posted by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) with karma: 113 on 2020-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0